# from column with factors to two different column with 0, 1

Tags: r

I have a column with group1 group 2 in data frame.

```
group <- c( "group1", "group1", "group2", "group1", "group2"  )
value<- c(1:5)
dat <- data.frame(value, group)
```

I want to make it like this-

```
group1 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
group2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
dat<- data.frame(value, group1, group2)
```

I tried this but have to remove the group column later

```
dat<-  dat %>%   
        mutate( group1 = ifelse(data1$group =="group1", 1, 0 ),
                group2 = ifelse(data1$group =="group2", 1, 0 ) )
```

Is there any other nice way to do this job.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can have `%>%  select(!"group")` at the end of the dplyr pipe. Also remove `data1$` from it - you probably meant `dat`, even that's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dummy column and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) -> result

#  value group1 group2
#  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1      1      0
#2     2      1      0
#3     3      0      1
#4     4      1      0
#5     5      0      1
```

Or in base R use `table` :

```
table(dat)

#    group
#value group1 group2
#    1      1      0
#    2      1      0
#    3      0      1
#    4      1      0
#    5      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert `%>%  select(!"group")` at the end of the dplyr pipe. Also remove data1$ from it - you probably meant dat, even that's not needed.

```
dat %>%   
        mutate(group1 = ifelse(group =="group1", 1, 0 ),
               group2 = ifelse(group =="group2", 1, 0 )) %>% 
        select(!"group")
```

> ```
>   value group1 group2
> 1     1      1      0
> 2     2      1      0
> 3     3      0      1
> 4     4      1      0
> 5     5      0      1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), value ~ group, length)
#   value group1 group2
#1:     1      1      0
#2:     2      1      0
#3:     3      0      1
#4:     4      1      0
#5:     5      0      1
```

---

Or this can be done with `pivot_wider` in a single step by specifying `values_fn`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = group,
     values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  value group1 group2
#  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     1      1      0
#2     2      1      0
#3     3      0      1
#4     4      1      0
#5     5      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
replace(
  out <- reshape(
    cbind(dat, q = 1),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "value",
    timevar = "group"
  ),
  is.na(out),
  0
)
```

giving

```
  value q.group1 q.group2
1     1        1        0
2     2        1        0
3     3        0        1
4     4        1        0
5     5        0        1
```